# Zooming a list plot without writing code

Tags: graphics, notebooks, user-interface

I would like to know if it is possible to simply zoom in or zoom out on a list plot without writing code.

I've read topics where they give code to add a scrollbar or something similar, but I just want to zoom using my mouse.

Isn't this possible?

Comment: Just click on the output a drag a corner to resize the plot.  Alternatively, open the toolbar beneath a plot and click on **image size**.

Comment: You can make the plot larger as stated in the comment above, but you can't retain the size of the plot and zoom in without using some code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible, so long as you don't demand to retain (add) a frame or axis on an arbitrary part of the plot.  That is if you are satisfied to zoom in on only a portion of the graphic, perhaps one that crops off the tick marks and labels.

To do that click on your graphic to reveal an orange frame with handles:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}]
```

[image]

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and drag one or more of the handles to select the part of the plot that interests you:

[image]

Now release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and drag a handle to resize at will:

[image]

Click off of the graphic and the frame will disappear:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Actually I think the real answer to your question is no, it isn't possible.

You will have to write a bit of code to get what (I think) you want. That is not terribly complicated and you can find example code elsewhere on this site.

Answer (score 2):

The comments give an answer to this question.

David G. Stork

> Just click on the output a drag a corner to resize the plot. Alternatively, open the toolbar beneath a plot and click on image size

Jack LaVigne

> You can make the plot larger as stated in the comment above, but you can't retain the size of the plot and zoom in without using some code